# How facebook pushes notifications, friend requests and other updates to its android mobile app?

Tags: android, facebook, server-push

What polling mechanism (implementation) does Facebook use to push data to its android mobile app ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is something you are looking for:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does not provide real time update of inbox, friend requests and notifications. How to get those ?

Comment: Yes, that's the saddest part of it, it is pretty limited as they have exposed only a few objects.

Comment: However as per facebook - 'You can not subscribe to changes on all properties and connections of the User object. Connections to which you can subscribe include: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins, location, events.'